# Choosing sorting algorithm for system of winning & losing

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a bunch of elements which have been compared to some other elements and either win or lose. There is not full data e.g. all elements compared to all other elements. Instead I have a list like this:

```
win_id | lose_id
12       73
992      25
22       12
2382     999
etc etc
```

I'd like to find a fairly fast algorithm for a large amount of elements, that also takes into consideration winning against someone who wins a lot (would be considered more significant than winning against a normal one).

Is Elo a good choice for this, or is there something that is able to run a bit faster? My separate use cases for this will be:

Finding top 10 (needs to be accurate)

Finding overall position (doesn't need perfect accuracy)

Comment: Yes that does work, but I'd like to do something where winning against someone with higher ranking gives you a higher ratio- do you know what I mean? .. (disappearing parent comment)

Comment: For a fast response you need to pre-compute, instead of sorting on demand.

Comment: Yes, I've worked a bit with Elo. And yes they can be cached, but do to  continuous input the rankings will quickly become inaccurate. So it works better for the top 10 as that can be daily or something, but minute by minute a lot of the ranks will change.

Comment: I know there are alternatives to Elo, because I've met ratings-math snobs (read, people who actually look through the system a little). However I couldn't help more than a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered combining ELO with something like a red-black tree to keep the data sorted?  ELO is the natural choice for what you describe, and it is about as fast as you can hope for, since updating ELOs is a constant time operation.

Then, you can keep the overall dataset sorted by ELO using a red-black tree.  Whenever a new match occurs, updating would then take O(log n): O(1) for recomputing each of the ELO scores, and then O(log n) for reconfiguring the Red-Black tree.  All of the other operations you describe: finding the top 10, or computing the rank of any given element, or finding the n'th element, would all be O(log n) operations.